# Do / While Loop Verification

Tags: java, while-loop, joptionpane, do-while

I'm using `javax.swing.JOptionPane`.

- I need the user to enter in the product number, revenue, and expenses.
- I need to **validate** the information to make sure that the revenue is between `0` and `20000` and  verify that the expenses are between `1500` and `10000`. I need to make sure that if they enter in an **invalid** revenue or expense it prompts them, and not allow the program to continue.
- The program needs to be able to determine if there was a net profit, loss, or break even.
- The user has to have the option of entering multiple records. Also, I need to count how many times the user entered in the information.

I feel like I was able to knock out a big chunk of the code.

When the user inputs an invalid revenue or expense, it keeps looping the messages and doesn't return to the ability to enter in the values again.

I also am not sure how I am going to get the user to input "Y" to loop the entire program again.

Can anyone lend me some assistance please?

```
/** 
 * The program will output the Product Number, Revenue, Expenses, as well as the Net Income 
 */
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;          // Access System.out
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RevenueJopt
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Declarations 
        double finalValue;
        char repeat;
        int counter = 1;
        String input;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Do Loop to run    
        do{
            // Advise the user the conditions that have to be met for inputs
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please ensure that your revenue is between 0 to 20,000.00 dollars." +
                    "\nPlease ensure that your expenses are between 1,500.000 to 10,000.00 dollars.");

            // Ask user the values of the variables
            String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter in a Product Number(or -1 to END)");
            String response1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Revenue?");
            String response2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Expenses?");
            // Read in values  
            int productNumber = Integer.parseInt(response);
            float revenue = Float.parseFloat(response1);
            float expenses = Float.parseFloat(response2);


            //While loop to Validate Information
            while(revenue < 0 || revenue > 20000 || expenses < 1500 || expenses > 10000) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have entered in either an invalid revenue or expense. Please enter in valid numbers.");
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Here is the product number you entered: " + productNumber + "."
                            + "\nHere is the revenue you entered: " + revenue + "."
                            + "\nHere are the expenses you entered: " + expenses + ".");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter in a Product Number (or-1 to END)"
                            + "\nEnter the Revenue"
                            + "\nEnter the Expenses");
                    //When this part runs, it goes into an infinite cycle. I am not sure how to break free of this. 
                    counter++;
                    //calculates final value
                } 
            }
            finalValue = revenue - expenses;
            // Calculates final value and displays as net profit, loss or break even. 
            if (finalValue > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You made a profit. Your net income is: "+finalValue);
            } else if (finalValue == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You broke even. Your revenue was "+ revenue +" your expenses were " +expenses);
            } else if (finalValue < 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have not made any profit. Your net loss is: "+finalValue);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number of records: " +counter);
            //validate user input   
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Would you like to input more records?");
            String response3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 'Y' for yes or 'N' for no.");

            // I am not sure how to hold the value "Y" to make the loop keep repeating
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            repeat = input.charAt(0);
            counter++;
        }
        while(repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
input = keyboard.nextLine();
repeat = input.charAt(0);
```

with

```
repeat = response3.charAt(0);
```

to get the first character of the String entered into the input dialog box.

However, this will throw an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the user enters nothing into the dialog box, so you have to decide on a default value for that case:

```
repeat = response3.isEmpty() ? 'n' : response3.charAt(0);
```

Reading from `System.in` is basically for CLI applications.

Also check the "validate information" while loop. If the user enters invalid values, he will be informed about this indefinitely, with no chance of entering correct values.